# add 9 hours to DATETIME field with PHP

Tags: php, datetime

i am getting `DATETIME` field from server.

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM table");

while($row = $result->fetch_array()){

     echo $row['add_time']; //2016-02-15 21:45:52
}
```

I want to add 9 hours to `$row['add_time']` so i can get `2016-02-16 06:45:52`. How can i do that using easiest way. i dont want to change `datetime` to seconds while using `strtotime()`.

**NOTE:** No, There is no similar question to that.

Answer (score 1):

What about using DateTime/DateInterval?

```
echo new \DateTime($row['add_time'])->add(new DateInterval('P9H'))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') ?
```

Comment: what is `\\` thing before datetime?

Comment: @WebberDepor It's just for the namespace.

Answer (score 0):

```
$row['add_time'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($row['add_time']) + (3600 * 9));
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it in the SQL:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT add_time + INTERVAL 9 HOUR FROM table");

while($row = $result->fetch_array()){

     echo $row['add_time']; //2016-02-15 21:45:52
}
```

You will get `2016-02-16 06:45:52`

Comment: @WebberDepor My answer is PHP.